# Mathematica: Variance[] definition

Tags: math, statistics, wolfram-mathematica, variance

The  section on the help system tells me the Variance[] function is equalvalent to:

```
Total[(list-Mean[list])^2]/(Length[list]-1)
```

But I think the right definition should be:

```
Total[(list-Mean[list])^2]/(Length[list])
```

I can't figure this out.

Comment: Please note that http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions is a much better place than this one for Mathematca related questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both definitions are correct:

- The first formula gives an unbiased estimator of the population variance when the population mean is *unknown*.
- The second formula gives an unbiased estimator of the population variance when the population mean is *known*.

When the true mean is unknown and has to be estimated from the data, the second formula would systematically underestimate the variance. The intuition is that a given sample would tend to have lower dispersion around the *estimated* mean than around the *true* mean. The `-1` in the denominator corrects for that.

See [Point estimation of the variance](http://www.statlect.com/variance_estimation.htm).